# Segmentation fault: 11 with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am experimenting with my code to try to add some new features in. After adding in the new UserDefaults I got an error that read "Segmentation fault: 11" and it flagged my secondviewcontoller, the code is down below. Please help

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

protocol DestinationViewDelegate {
}
    var delegate : GameViewDelegate! = nil

var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
var ghost = SKSpriteNode()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, GameViewDelegate {

var sw = false
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBAction func one(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(1, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost one was selected")
}

@IBAction func two(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(2, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost two was selected")
}

@IBAction func three(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(3, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost three was selected")
}

@IBAction func four(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(4, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost four was selected")
}

@IBAction func five(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(5, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost five was selected")
}

@IBAction func six(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        defaults.set(6, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost six was selected")
}


@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchpressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    if mySwitch.isOn{
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "SwitchState")

        if bombSoundEffect != nil {
            bombSoundEffect.stop()
            bombSoundEffect = nil

        }

    }
    else{
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "SwitchState")

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Untitled2.wav", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)


        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            bombSoundEffect = sound
            sound.numberOfLoops = -1
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }

    }


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Keep this part the same
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if (defaults.object(forKey: "SwitchState") != nil) {
        mySwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "SwitchState")
    }

    // Check to see if the switch is off, if so, stop the music

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Something is probably nil.  Which line has the exception.  What is the exception message?

Comment: @Paulw11 i just added in a picture with error

Comment: Which line is SecondViewController.swift:26? That is the cause of the segfault. You are crashing the compiler.

Comment: @Paulw11 No! Segfault is a _compiler_ crash. It is not an exception or a runtime error.

Comment: @matt a segfault is a runtime error, not a compiler crash. it is the result of trying to read or write to illegal memory locations during the runtime of the process.

Comment: @Erik. Not this segfault. What's running and erroring is the Swift compiler. Trust me.

Comment: In  this case it is a runtime error in the compiler, not in the execution of the app.  Until the screenshot was added it could have been either and a runtime app crash was more likely

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: Not related to the crash, but those three variables `delegate`, `bombSoundEffect` and `ghost` probably should be in your class, not globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this bit of code:

```
@IBAction func one(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults.set(1, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost one was selected")
}
```

You've found a compiler bug. Try to work around it like this:

```
@IBAction func one(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults.set(1 as Any, forKey: "Sphere")
    print("Ghost one was selected")
}
```

You will need to do that for all your `defaults.set` calls. I think that will allow you to compile.

Comment: Gosh, this was a life-saver! Is there any way these bugs can be reported to Apple?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto That bug is now fixed, I believe. If it isn't fixed for you, could you update to the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.2, installed on `2016-12-15`. Anyway, your fix works fine so it's no big deal.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto And you are segfaulting? I cannot reproduce any segfault with the code shown. Can you?

Comment: I didn't try with an integer, but with a code having the same problem (in my case an array `[Any]` that needed to be explicitly casted `as [Any]`).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I still can't reproduce. I tried `defaults.set([1,2,3], ...`, no problem.

Comment: It wasn't a constant array, but it was built at runtime. In any case, no big deal because your fix worked and I had to change my code anyway. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto You don't understand. I want to crash like you. Show me how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132737/discussion-between-andrea-lazzarotto-and-matt).